# Do I have to make variables and methods private if I am the only one who touch the code?

Tags: android, encapsulation

I have created an app and it works pretty well, I'm the only one who write the code for the app, most of the variables and methods are not private. Should I make them private even if they haven't been used in other classes or activities? As I said the app works as expected.

Comment: if you are schizophrenic then yes :)

Answer (score 1):

I try to limit access to classes, methods and variables as much as possible, even if I am the only one editing the code. I think that this way you can avoid errors (e.g. accidentally changing data from code that is not responsible for it) and, with reasonable encapsulation, errors in the architecture are noticed more quickly. Too lax handling of access rights leads to unclean code in my eyes.